# Java - variable nave might not have been initialized

Tags: java, poo

El problema o error lo tengo en el case "2", el IntelliJ me pone el siguiente error:

**java: variable nave might not have been initialized**

Tengo un contador para cuando se crea una nave, es decir, controlo si una nave está creada para saber si la imprime o no... no lo entiendo, quizás me he olvidado de algo, pero en mi cabeza la solución es así de simple con un contador, pero parece que no

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String entradaUsuario = "";
    String menu = "----------------------------------------\n" +
            "1. Crear nave espacial\n" +
            "2. Mostrar ASCIIart de la nave\n" +
            "3. Acelerar nave\n" +
            "4. Frenar nave\n" +
            "5. Parar nave\n" +
            "Q. Salir del programa\n" +
            "----------------------------------------";
    int navesCreadas = 0;

    while (!entradaUsuario.equals("Q")) {
        System.out.println(menu);
        System.out.print("Qué desea hacer: ");
        entradaUsuario = scanner.nextLine();

        switch (entradaUsuario){
            case "1":
                System.out.print("Introduce el nombre de tu nave");
                String nombre = scanner.nextLine();
                System.out.print("Introduce la matrícula galáctica de tu nave");
                String matriculaGalactica = scanner.nextLine();
                System.out.print("Introduce la acecleración de tu nave");
                float aceleracion = scanner.nextFloat();
                scanner.nextLine();
                SpaceShip nave = new SpaceShip(nombre, matriculaGalactica, aceleracion);
                navesCreadas++;
                break;
            case "2":
                if (navesCreadas > 0) {
                System.out.println(nave);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("No hay nave creada para representar");
                }
                break;
            case "3":
                break;
            case "4":
                break;
            case "5":
                break;
            case "Q":
                System.out.println("Saliendo del programa...");
                break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Lee sobre ambito de variables... nave esta definida, pero no ahi, en otro lado... es mas... cuando salis del case 1, nave no existe mas....

Comment: Estás tratando de usar el objeto `nave` dentro del `case "2"` habiéndolo declarado dentro del `case "1"`. Pon la declaración del objeto afuera del `while`, al nivel de `navesCreadas`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como mencionan en los comentarios, el problema está en que nave no existe más que en el `case 1`.

Imagínate esta situación:

1. El usuario inicia el programa
2. El usuario selecciona la opción 2

¿Dónde se creó la nave? ¿Qué onda con la nave?. No existe...

De igual manera no necesitas un contador, lo puedes lograr si inicializas tu objeto como ***null***

```java
package main;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String entradaUsuario = null;
        String menu = "----------------------------------------\n" +
                "1. Crear nave espacial\n" +
                "2. Mostrar ASCIIart de la nave\n" +
                "3. Acelerar nave\n" +
                "4. Frenar nave\n" +
                "5. Parar nave\n" +
                "Q. Salir del programa\n" +
                "----------------------------------------";

        SpaceShip nave = null;

        while (!"Q".equals(entradaUsuario)) {
            System.out.println(menu);
            System.out.print("Qué desea hacer: ");
            entradaUsuario = scanner.nextLine();

            switch (entradaUsuario){
                case "1":
                    System.out.print("Introduce el nombre de tu nave");
                    String nombre = scanner.nextLine();
                    System.out.print("Introduce la matrícula galáctica de tu nave");
                    String matriculaGalactica = scanner.nextLine();
                    System.out.print("Introduce la acecleración de tu nave");
                    float aceleracion = scanner.nextFloat();
                    scanner.nextLine();
                    nave = new SpaceShip(nombre, matriculaGalactica, aceleracion);
                    break;
                case "2":
                    if (nave != null) {
                        System.out.println(nave);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("No hay nave creada para representar");
                    }
                    break;
                case "3":
                    break;
                case "4":
                    break;
                case "5":
                    break;
                case "Q":
                    System.out.println("Saliendo del programa...");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    private static class SpaceShip {
        String nombre;
        String matriculaGalactica;
        float aceleracion;

        public SpaceShip(String nombre, String matriculaGalactica, float aceleracion) {
            this.nombre = nombre;
            this.matriculaGalactica = matriculaGalactica;
            this.aceleracion = aceleracion;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "La nave \"" + nombre +
                    "\" con matricula galáctica \"" + matriculaGalactica +
                    "\" tiene una aceleración de " + aceleracion + " m/s";
        }
    }

}
```

**Nota:** el `private static class` hace referencia a una clase anidada, para no complicarte sigue con tu modelo actual. **NO ES NECESARIO USAR CLASES INTERNAS NI ANIDADAS**